# Compare two date-input-field-values with JQuery and attr. disabled:false to button

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I've set up an HTML form and some JQuery. Date-input in the form is stored in a cookie. If the cookies are set, the button "set other dates" is visible. If cookies are not set, the date-input-form is visible.

HTML:

```
<form id="datesinput" style="display: none;">
  <h3>Select dates:</h3>
  <lable>Check in</lable>
  <input type="date" id="checkindate" name="checkindate" value="" required/>
  <lable>Check out:</lable>
  <input type="date" id="checkoutdate" name="checkoutdate" value="" required/>
      <select id="currency" required>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
     </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="hotelid" name="hotelid" value="123" /><br />
  <input type="button" id="datesubmit" name="datesubmit" value="Submit dates" disabled/>
</form>

<div id="rates" style="display: none;">
  <a id="book-btn" href="#">Book from: <span id="price">0</span> / night</a>
  <a id="reset-btn">Select other dates</a>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
// Check if cookies are set and show form or rates

$(document).ready(function() {

  var checkInCookie = $.cookie('checkInDate');
  var checkOutCookie = $.cookie('checkOutDate');
  var checkCurrency = $.cookie('currency');

  if (checkInCookie && checkOutCookie && checkCurrency != null) {
    $('#datesinput').hide();
    $('#rates').show();
  } else {
    $('#datesinput').show();
    $('#rates').hide();
  }
});

// Attr. disabled to formsubmit, as long as checkin date and checkout dates are set

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#datesubmit').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#checkindate, #checkoutdate').change(function() {

    if ($(this).val().length != 0)
      $('#datesubmit').attr('disabled', false);
    else
      $('#datesubmit').attr('disabled', true);

  })
});


// Set cookies on formsubmit

$("#datesubmit").click(function() {

  $.cookie("checkInDate", $("#checkindate").val());
  $.cookie("checkOutDate", $("#checkoutdate").val());
  $.cookie("currency", $("#currency").val());

  $("#rates").show();
  $("#datesinput").hide();

});

// Delete cookies onclick

$("#reset-btn").click(function() {

  $("#rates").hide();
  $("#datesinput").show();
  $.removeCookie("checkInDate");
  $.removeCookie("checkOutDate");
  $.removeCookie("currency");

});
```

What I try to achieve is, that the buton with the ID#datesubmit is enabled, when *both* input fields #checkindate and #checkoutdate are not empty, AND #checkindate is smaller than #checkoutdate.

Right now, I just check on a change on one of the input fields and enable the button then.

If anyone could help me with an elegant way to check for both fields, I would be glad.

Thanks in advance!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phii/doL8861r/)

PS: Thanks a lot to user: @gaetanoM - Exactly what I described. 
Additional question: Is it possible to set the #checkindate smaller than the #checkoutdate, but not bigger than 30 days apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to change this line:

```
if ($(this).val().length != 0)
```

with:

```
if (new Date($('#checkindate').val()) < new Date($('#checkoutdate').val()))
```

The updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doL8861r/4/)